Reanimated scrollview contentOffset animation disables all gestures on IOS
Animating the contentOffset prop on a reanimated scrollview disables all gestures including touch events on IOS while the animation is running. The animation itself works fine and as soon as the animation is canceled the touch events start working again. Everything works fine on android.
Important packages:
"expo": "^51.0.18",
"expo-router": "~3.5.17",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",

_layout.tsx:
return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          ...omitted
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );

ScrollView component:
const offsetX = useSharedValue<number>(0);

  const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => ({
    contentOffset: {
      x: offsetX.value,
      y: 0
    }
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
      offsetX.value = withRepeat(withTiming(getOffsetXEndPosition() , { duration: 25000, easing: Easing.linear }), -1, true);
  }, [xxx]);

<Animated.ScrollView
        onTouchStart={() => cancelAnimation(offsetX)}
        animatedProps={animatedProps}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      >
...omitted
</Animated.ScrollView>

It's specifically adding an animation like 'withTiming' or 'withSpring' that causes the gestures to be disabled. Setting the offset value directly works fine.
UPDATE:
I have found that the problem is because the animated scrollview is nested inside another scrollview. Removing the outer scrollview re-enables the touch events. Unfortunately it's not an option to remove the outer scrollview and I still have no idea how to fix it:
<ScrollView style={styles.container} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} >
     ...Many components here
     <ComponentWithScrollViewInside />
</ScrollView>


I never found the root cause, but you can use Gesture detector from react-native-gesture-handler as a work around:
  export interface GestureTapHandlerProps {
  onPress?: () => void;
  children: React.ReactElement;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

const GestureTapHandler = ({
  onPress,
  children,
  disabled
}: GestureTapHandlerProps) => {
  const tapHandler = Gesture.Tap()
    .onEnd(() => {
      console.log("Click", onPress, disabled);
      if (onPress && !disabled) {
        onPress();
      }
    })
    .runOnJS(true);

  return <GestureDetector gesture={tapHandler}>{children}</GestureDetector>;
};

